# How to show rows values as column in gridview using C#

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have a table and I want to show my table rows as column name in gridview using C#. Please can anyone suggest how to do this?

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[duedate]
(
     [duedateid] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
     [duedate] [nvarchar](50) NULL
)

SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[duedate] ON

INSERT [dbo].[duedate] ([duedateid], [duedate]) VALUES (1, N'Apr')
INSERT [dbo].[duedate] ([duedateid], [duedate]) VALUES (2, N'May')
INSERT [dbo].[duedate] ([duedateid], [duedate]) VALUES (3, N'Jun')
INSERT [dbo].[duedate] ([duedateid], [duedate]) VALUES (4, N'Jul')
INSERT [dbo].[duedate] ([duedateid], [duedate]) VALUES (5, N'Aug')
INSERT [dbo].[duedate] ([duedateid], [duedate]) VALUES (6, N'Sep')
INSERT [dbo].[duedate] ([duedateid], [duedate]) VALUES (7, N'Oct')
INSERT [dbo].[duedate] ([duedateid], [duedate]) VALUES (8, N'Nov')
INSERT [dbo].[duedate] ([duedateid], [duedate]) VALUES (9, N'Dec')
INSERT [dbo].[duedate] ([duedateid], [duedate]) VALUES (10, N'Jan')
INSERT [dbo].[duedate] ([duedateid], [duedate]) VALUES (11, N'Feb')
INSERT [dbo].[duedate] ([duedateid], [duedate]) VALUES (12, N'Mar')

SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[duedate] OFF
```

I want to show this column value as column name like

```
Sr.No   Apr   May  Jun  Jul  Aug  Set  Oct  Nov  Dec Jan Fe Mar
```

my gridview code is below

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
     BackColor="White" BorderColor="#336666" BorderStyle="Double" BorderWidth="3px" 
     CellPadding="4" GridLines="Horizontal">
     <RowStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#333333" />
         <Columns>
              <asp:BoundField DataField="duedateid" HeaderText="Fee" />
              <asp:BoundField DataField="duedate" HeaderText="Total" />
         </Columns>
         <FooterStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#333333" />
         <PagerStyle BackColor="#336666" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
         <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#339966" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
         <HeaderStyle BackColor="#336666" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
</asp:GridView>
```

My c# code to bind gridview data from database

```
     public void bindgvduedate()
    {
        con = new SqlConnection();
        con.ConnectionString =         ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["con1"].ConnectionString;
        con.Open();
        DataTable table = new DataTable();
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("select *from duedate",con);
        da.Fill(table );
        GridView1.DataSource= table;
        GridView1.DataBind();
        con.Close();

    }
```

calling of function at page load

```
 using System;
 using System.Collections;
 using System.Configuration;
 using System.Data;
 using System.Linq;
 using System.Web;
 using System.Web.Security;
 using System.Web.UI;
 using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;
 using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
 using System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts;
 using System.Xml.Linq;
 using System.Data.SqlClient;
 namespace egurkul
 {
  public partial class feeRecipt : System.Web.UI.Page
   {

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        bindgvduedate();
    }
}
```

Comment: Always show your efforts. Don't simply ask if someone wants to write the code for you.

Comment: where do you want to do this? SQL or c#??

Comment: using c# in gridview

Answer (score 0):

This task seems to be related with using PIVOT in SQL. PIVOT clause can convert rows into columns. In your case you should know what kind of aggregation is going to be used. I've come with solution like this:

```
SELECT 'max(duedateid)' SrNo, *
FROM
(
    SELECT  d.duedate, d.duedateid
    FROM duedate AS d
) AS s
PIVOT
(
    MAX(duedateid) FOR duedate
    IN(
        [Jan], [Feb], [Mar], [Apr], [May], [Jun], [Jul], [Aug], [Sep], [Oct], [Nov], [Dec]
    )
) AS pvt
```